# Apply Button borders like gmail "create new account " button

Tags: jquery, css

Can any one suggest me on how to style a button like gmail's "Create new account".  Below i am giving the image of that button
[image]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can't you just look at the CSS they use on that page, or if it's an image do a _tiny_ bit of research and create the same effect using gradients? Take the initiative, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css"> 
button
{
border:2px solid #a1a1a1;
padding:10px 40px; 
background:#dddddd;
width:300px;
border-radius:15px;
-moz-border-radius:25px; /* Firefox 3.6 and earlier */
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button style="height: 70px; width: 400px">Create Account</button>

</body>
</html>
```